# MKMapView - How to load all default Apple annotations

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview

I am developing a app that is going to use a map. I was wondering how to load all the POIs that already appear on the default Apple's map app?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by default POIs?

Comment: When you use the default iOS map you can see the names of business and even click and obtain some info. However, when I'm using the MKMapView this names do not appear on the map. Is there any setting? And I don't know why my question was voted down

Comment: Please consider voting up or green ticking the answer if you find it helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least no built in functionality in MapKit. You'll have to use Google's webservices to fetch those POIs (like Places API). You should have a look at the [Google Places API Web Services](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?hl=en)!

I'm not sure why your question was voted down, I guess you need to do some self-research before posting any questions.  A lot of times, similar questions have been asked. You just need to look.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try to find something with no success that's why I post here. Regarding to your answer iOS6 is not going to use google as a source. Therefore I thought that Apple would provide some internal API.

Comment: I agree. At this point it's going to be difficult to find any information on this site about ios 6. You might want to try posting in the official apple developer forums if you are enrolled into the paid Apple developer program. Let me know if you find any solutions. I'm curious to know too.